# withdraw amount from stripe account to cutomer bank account using stripe api in laravel 8?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-8, payout

How can I transfer some amount in stripe account to customer bank account using stripe API ?

I am working on an implementation of REST API for a mobile application which encapsulates feature of earned points in form of money equivalent to points using Stripe as a payment gateway . To accomplish it I have used Stripe payout API to transfer amount directly into destination bank account.

Comment: You'd use [Payouts](https://stripe.com/docs/payouts) to send balance to the external account of a Stripe account. I guess as Laravel is a PHP framework, you could use the [Stripe PHP library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php). Here's the related [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/create?lang=php).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.